# Inkscape: Stroke width different when exporting .pptx to PDF

Tags: inkscape, pdf, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-word

So I created an infographic in Inkscape that I use in my Powerpoint-Presentation (Office 2016). When I save my presentation as .pdf, the stroke width changes (it becomes much thicker). The same happens when using Word. Using the .pptx and .docx file, the graphic looks just good there and it is also fine when directly exporting as pdf from Inkscape using the default settings.

I tried using print to pdf (instead of save as pdf), and the strokes maintain their original width, but the graphic seems to be rasterized (does not happen with other svgs!) and shows artifacts of heavy compression.

So how can I solve this issue? I could of course just export an extremely high-resolution .png and use this, but I'd like to use the .svg.

I use Windows 10.

---

**Update:**

I tried converting the svg to emf in Inkscape. Now the borders look fine when exporting to .pdf, but small shapes are just converted to circular shapes with the fill color of the shape. How can this be avoided?

Comment: A guess . Maybe try converting strokes to paths in Inkscape.  Select all, and do Object > Stroke to path.  To be honest with you, I'm not sure how well MS products support SVG standards. That might be the real source of the problem here.

Comment: Maybe I had a [similar problem](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/143667/problem-with-text-write-on-inkscape-and-put-on-word) but using  the .wmf I've resolved