# Problem with text write on inkscape and put on Microsoft-Word

Tags: inkscape, text, microsoft-word

#### Here's the explainations of the problem...

Not many words are needed because it is quite visible.

| Image | Location |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Img on inkscape] | I wrote a small text attached to the image in **INKSCAPE**. |
| [image: Img on inkscape] | As you can see, however, the result in **WORD** is this ... |

I've tried `text>convert to text` but doesn't work.
The file I'm trying to put in word is in SVG format.

With `PDf` type

[image: Pdf format]
**How can i solve?**

> ✨ I'm a newbie please be gentle ✨

Comment: So I don't use Inkscape, but it does seem like you were on the right track except that I don't know how converting text to text would do anything. I have no idea why Inkscape would even have such a feature or what it would do. But converting text to paths should get around the issue. If my googling is correct, I think you can convert text to paths with: `Path > Object to path`. Another possible workaround would be exporting to another format, like PDF or even PNG... especially if you don't need to print it. Honestly, I'd expect PDF to work without any changes.

Comment: The `png` makes the image blurry for me and since there are really small sentences I would like a good resolution of the image... 
Thanks for suggestion about Path now I will try it.

Comment: Don't skip trying PDF. SVG is somewhat notorious for having text related issues in many different situations, but I'd be surprised if PDF produced this same issue. They're both vector formats so nothing would really change... aside from the issue going away hopefully.

Comment: Okay, I was reading some `WMF` files and it looks like they would implement well in the word document I am finishing up.
Anyway I have to test the `PDF` and I think I will do it shortly.

Comment: I've **tested** the `pdf` but I did not like it because the image being small if it is enlarged it becomes grainy

Comment: What do you mean with grainy? Can you screenshot that? I'm just curious what that looks like and how that would be possible (assuming the PDF doesn't contain raster images).

Comment: Pixelated is the term I would use. But yea, there are two possibilities: The PDF could contain raster images, which won't scale well, but there's no way the image in the question has anything raster in it unless something really funky happened. The likely reason is that your Word version doesn't have a proper support for PDF files. Newer versions handle PDF just fine, but I remember there being some issues in older versions of Word. I could be wrong, but I seem to remember Word kind of converting PDF files to raster when placed in (or whatever), which seems to fit with what you're describing.

Comment: I can't vote in favor of your comment because I'm too low-level, but I think it's reasonable to think it's an Word problem ...
Thanks for the help, I have now used the WMF format and it works fine for me✨

Comment: WMF is quite the legacy format though and not without it's own issues... Not to shit on WMF (or EMF), but looking at the screenshot some text is getting cut off vertically in the answer you posted below. Is it just a screenshot thing (zoom maybe)? It's happening in the kind of second row of info boxes on the left and right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Then I Solved

---

I changed my file from Svg to WMF and the format works better, just as it should.

[image: Finally]

Thanks for helps✨
[WMF File are...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile)